# How to implement a function to create an object?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

There is object:

```
const filters = ref<filterType>({
  date: {
    value: '',
  },
  user: {
    value: '',
  },
  userId: {
    value: '',
  },
...
```

There is a function for sending data, to which an object is passed as a parameter based on filters's ref:

```
({ 
  date: filters.value.date.value || undefined,
  user: filters.value.user.value || undefined,
  userId: filters.value.userId.value || undefined,
  ... 
})
```

Then I need the same object that but in different function. In order not to duplicate two large objects, I probably need to implement a function that will create this object. How to implement it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create and export a function that returns the object based on `filters`:

```
export const getFilterParams = (filters: filterType) => ({
  date: filters.value.date.value || undefined,
  user: filters.value.user.value || undefined,
  userId: filters.value.userId.value || undefined,
  ...
});
```

You would call it like that:

```
const params = getFilterParams(filters.value);
```